# Java Util Optional code to Guava Optional map and filter

Tags: java, spring, guava, option-type

what will be equivalent of below Java util optional code to Guava Optional:

```
private Optional<Integer> parseIntegerProperty(String property) {
            return Optional.ofNullable(property)
                           .filter(StringUtils::isNumeric)
                           .map(Integer::valueOf);
        }
```

Comment: how to change the filter ?

Answer (score 2):

Guava's `Optional` doesn't have filter method and [won't ever have one](https://github.com/google/guava/issues/856):

> Not inclined to add new features to our legacy `Optional` class; try to move to `java.util.Optional` if you can.

That said, you really want to use another Guava utility, [`Ints#tryParse(String)`](https://guava.dev/releases/28.0-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/primitives/Ints.html#tryParse-java.lang.String-), or if you insist with Guava `Optional`:

```
private Optional<Integer> parseIntegerPropertyGuava(String property) {
    return Optional.fromNullable(Ints.tryParse(property));
}
```

Comment: Plus one for `tryParse`, a hidden gem of Guava.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you need a Guava optional value to provide to some legacy API that hasn't switched to the Java one. In that case, why not use a Java optional "until the end", just before you call the legacy API:

```
private java.util.Optional<Integer> parseIntegerProperty(String property) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(property)
                   .filter(StringUtils::isNumeric)
                   .map(Integer::valueOf);
}

// ...
java.util.Optional<Integer> javaOptional = parseIntegerProperty("123")
someLegacyAPI(com.google.common.base.Optional.fromJavaUtil(javaOptional);
```